# Why is every positive linear map between $C^*$-algebras bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

We know that every positive linear functional on a $C^*$-algebra is bounded.

How can we prove every positive linear map between $C^*$-algebras is bounded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [positive linear functionals are bounded in $C^\*$-algebras](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296591/positive-linear-functionals-are-bounded-in-c-algebras)

Comment: @Norbert: This question is about positive linear *maps*, not functionals. Also, the method in the answer to the other thread only applies to unital domains. While the reduction to the unital case is easy for positive linear functionals, that doesn't seem to apply to positive linear maps.

Comment: @Martin my bad, didn't read carefully

Answer (score 18):

Let $\phi:A\longrightarrow B$ be a positive linear map between two $C^*$-algebras. We will show that $\phi$ is automatically bounded. We can assume that $B$ is unital without loss of generality, but this does not change anything. The problem is with $A$. Here is a proof I learned in [Blackadar's book](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Operator_Algebras.html?id=6b_T1j3Ib8oC&redir_esc=y) which works whether $A$ is unital or not, for positive linear functionals like for positive linear maps in general. We will eventually use the partial order on self-adjoint elements $x\leq y$ if $y-x$ is positive. By assumption, $x\leq y$ implies $\phi(x)\leq \phi(y)$. Note that for $z$ self-adjoint in $B$ unital, we have $\|z\|\leq M$ if and only if $-M1\leq z\leq M1$.

1) Every $x\in A$ can be written  $x=h+ik$ with $h,k$ self-adjoint, $\|h\|\leq \|x\|$ and $\|k\|\leq \|x\|$. Indeed, set $h:=\frac{x+x^*}{2}$ and $k:=\frac{x-x^*}{2i}$. So it suffices to prove that $\phi$ is bounded on self-adjoint elements.

2) Every self-adjoint $x=x^*\in A$ can be written $x=x_+-x_-$ with $x_+,x_-$ positive and $\|x_+\|\leq \|x\|$, $\|x_-\|\leq \|x\|$. Indeed, by functional calculus, take $f_+(t)=\max(t,0)=\frac{|t|+t}{2}$ and $f_-(t)=\max(-t,0)=\frac{|t|-t}{2}$. Then set $x_+:=f_+(x)$ and $x_-:=f_-(x)$. So it suffices to prove that $\phi$ is bounded on positive elements.

3) Assume for a contradiction that $\phi$ is not bounded on positive elements and take $x_n$ a sequence of positive elements such that $\|x_n\|=1$ and $\|\phi(x_n)\|\geq 4^n$. Now set $x:=\sum_{n\geq 1}2^{-n}x_n\in A$. For every $n\geq 1$, $x\geq 2^{-n}x_n$ whence $\phi(x)\geq \phi(2^{-n}x_n)$ and therefore $\|\phi(x)\|\geq \|2^{-n}\phi(x_n)\|\geq 2^{-n}4^n=2^n$. Contradiction since $\|\phi(x)\|<\infty$.

**Note:** with more work, we can prove that if $A,B$ are unital and if $\phi:A\longrightarrow B$ is a unital linear map, then $\phi$ is positive if and only if $\|\phi\|=1$.

Comment: How do you apply the reduction exactly? *("So it suffices to prove [...].")*

Comment: In (3), you seem to use that $\phi$ is order-preserving. And then the norm also. Is this a triviality..? EDIT: ah, yes, of course it is for $\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\zhang}[1]{{\Large{\text{#1}}}}
\def \A{\mathscr A} \def \F{\mathbb{F}} \def \N{\mathbb{N}} \def \R{\mathbb{R}} \def \C{\mathbb{C}}\def \H{\mathscr{H}}\def \d{\mathrm{d}} \def \Inv{\mathrm{Inv}}
\def \ni{^{-1}} \def \jx{\lim_{n\to\infty}} \def \yb{\frac{1}{2}}
\newcommand{\x}{\times} \newcommand{\wt}{\textbf{Question.}} \newcommand{\bh}[1]{\textbf{#1.}} \newcommand{\xl}[2]{#1_1, #1_2, \cdots, #1_{#2}} \newcommand{\xl}[2]{#1_1, #1_2, \cdots, #1_{#2}} \newcommand{\tm}[1]{\textbf{ #1.}} \renewcommand{\l}[1]{\lVert #1\rVert}\newcommand{\zm}{Proof.} \newcommand{\zb}{}$

Suppose $\varphi:A\to B$ is a positive linear map between $C^*$ algebra, then for all positive linear functional $\tau$ on $B$, $\tau\circ\varphi $ is a positive linear functional on $A$ and thus bounded, i.e.$$\lVert\tau\circ\varphi(x)\rVert\leq M_\tau ~~ (\forall x\in A \text{ satisfying } \l{x}\leq 1)$$ for some positive constant $M_\tau$.

Every bounded linear functional on $B$ is a linear combination of 4 positive linear functionals on $B$ by Jordan Decomposition, thus for all $b^*\in B^*,$ $$\l{b^*(\varphi(x))}\leq M_{b^*} ~~( \forall x\in A \text{ satisfying } \l{x}\leq 1)$$for some positive constant $M_{b^*}$. Hence $\l{\varphi(x)}\leq M$ for some positive constant $M$ by the Principle of Uniform Boundedness, i.e. $\varphi$ is bounded.