# Continuity of a positive preserving operator between C(X) and C(Y)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, vector-lattices

I've been struggling with this question in Reed and Simon while I'm prepping for quals.

> Suppose that $T:C(X)\rightarrow C(Y)$ is a positive operator. Prove that T is continuous and $\Vert T\Vert_{C(Y)^{*}}=\Vert T1\Vert_{C(Y)}$.

The proof for positive linear functionals doesn't carry over and I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: What is $T_1$? ${}{}$

Comment: Use the map with the function $x\mapsto\lVert f\rVert_\infty-f(x)$, $f\in C(X)$.

Comment: @copper.hat It's the sup norm in $C(Y)$ of T applied to the constant function that evaluates to 1.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Applying T to that function works in the case that we're dealing with real-valued continuous functions. What about the complex case?

Comment: The proof does carry over. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426487/why-is-every-positive-linear-map-between-c-algebras-bounded