# Positive Map: Reduction

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Given C*-algebras $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$.
*(Both possibly nonunital!)*

Linear Map:
$$\varphi:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}:\quad\varphi\in\mathcal{L}$$

Implication:
$$\varphi\geq0\implies\|\varphi\|<\infty$$
*(Reduction?)*

*Reference: [Boundedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/426619/79762)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\|\varphi(A)\|\leq c\,\|A\|$ when $A$ is selfadjoint, then for arbitrary $A$ you have 
$$
\|\varphi(A)\|=\|\varphi(\text{Re}\,A)+i\varphi(\text{Im}\,A)\|
\leq\|\varphi(\text{Re}\,A)\|+\|\varphi(\text{Im}\,A)\|\\ \leq c\,(\|\text{Re}\,A\|+\|\text{Im}\,A)\|\leq 2c\|A\|,
$$
since
$$
\|\text{Re}A\|=\frac12\,\|A+A^*\|\leq\frac12\,(\|A\|+\|A^*\|)=\|A\|.
$$

Comment: Ah ok nice!! :) And what about reduction from selfadjoint to positive?

Comment: Every selfadjoint is a difference of two positives.

Comment: Ah ok and we know that: $A_\pm:=\frac12\{|A|\pm A\}\in\mathcal{A}$

Comment: Yes indeed. $ $