# $C^{*}$-algebra and continuous linear map

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^{*}$-algebra with identity and abelian condition.‎

If $\varphi\colon A \to \mathbb{C}$ is a linear map so that for all‎ $a\in A$, $\varphi (a^{*} a ) \geq 0$.

How can I show that $ \varphi$ is continuous?‎

Please help me.

Comment: There is an answer to a more general question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426487/why-is-every-positive-linear-map-between-c-algebras-bounded

Comment: We know that every positive linear map between C∗-algebras is bounded.Does it  matter whether $ a$ is self-adjoint or not ? I mean in question $ ‎\varphi (‎ ‎a‎^{*}‎a) ‎ ‎\geq 0‎‎$‎

Comment: Whether or not $a$ is self-adjoint, $a^*a$ is always positive, and further every positive element of $A$ can be written as $c^*c$ for some $c$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [positive linear functionals are bounded in $C^*$-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296591/positive-linear-functionals-are-bounded-in-c-algebras)

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that $A$ is unital, the argument is much simpler.

For $a\geq0$, we have 
$$
\varphi(a)\leq\varphi(\|a\|\,I)=\varphi(I)\,\|a\|.
$$
Since every $a\in A$ is a linear combination of four positives (with coefficients that have absolute value $1$, and each positive with norm at most the norm of $a$), we get
$$
|\varphi(a)|\leq 4\|a\|\,\varphi(I). 
$$
So $\varphi$ is bounded and $\|\varphi\|\leq4\varphi(I)$.

The above estimates are extremely crude, though: in reality, we always have $\|\varphi\|=\varphi(I)$.