# Prove that : an operator $\ell$ satisfying, $\ell(f)\ge 0$ whenever $f\ge 0$ is bounded on $C_b(X)$ .

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

While reading some functional analysis note I came across the following theorem.

**[Riesz-Markov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem): (for linear forms on Wiener spaces)** If $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff space and $\ell : C_b(X)\to \Bbb R. $ is a linear and continuous form satisfying $\ell(f)\ge 0$ whenever $f\ge 0$. Then there exists a unique Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that $$\ell(f) = \int_X f d\mu, ~~~~\forall~~f\in C_b(X).$$
 Where $C_b(X)$ is the space of bounded functions on $X.$

The document says the following statement: Such operators $\ell$ satisfying: $\ell(f)\ge 0$ whenever $f\ge 0$   is automatically bounded.

> How to prove that $\ell$ is bounded on $C_b(X)$.
>   I though it could be a good idea to share this on MSE.

Comment: For anyone looking, [a much more general statement holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426487/why-is-every-positive-linear-map-between-c-algebras-bounded), and there are also [proofs for linear maps on C$^*$-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296591/positive-linear-functionals-are-bounded-in-c-algebras).

Comment: Guy Fsone, I will point out that there is a new thread on meta which seems to be related to your activity on the site: [Why so many Riesz Representation questions in such short time?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27508#27509)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact: we have $$\|f\|_\infty\pm f\ge 0\implies \ell(1)\|f\|_\infty\pm \ell(f) \overset{\text{linearity}}{=} \ell(\|f\|_\infty)\pm \ell(f)\overset{\text{linearity}}{=}\ell(\|f\|_\infty\pm f) \ge 0$$

That is for all $f\in C_b(X)$ we have, $$ |\ell(f)| = \pm\ell(f) \le \ell(1)\|f\|_\infty.$$
this prove the continuity of $\ell$ and hence $\ell \in (C_b(X))^*$